# How do we upgrade Lesscss to the most recent version in Windows using NPM?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, less, npm, upgrade

I have recently upgraded my website from Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3. In compiling the bootstrap.less, I am running into errors with the semi-colon separated parameters. The fix is apparently to upgrade to the most recent version of Lesscss. I have tried the following:

- open a node.js command prompt and run the following
- npm install less

This doesn't do the trick. What needs to be done to properly update lesscss?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
npm update less
npm update -g less
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems more pithy. I guess I don't need to uninstall first.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to upgrade, use Slawa Eremkin's answer.

If you really want to see what's going on, open a node.js command prompt and run the following:

```
// list installed modules
npm list 
npm list -g 

// uninstall less 
npm uninstall less 
npm uninstall -g less 

// test
npm list 
npm list -g 

// install
npm install less
npm install -g less

// test again
npm list 
npm list -g
```

Done. Note: the -g flag is for globally install modules. I decided to uninstall and re-install both globally and otherwise, although I am not sure that this is required.